# Difference between plus() vs add() in Kotlin List

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I want to know the difference between plus() and add() in Kotlin List.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    val firstList = mutableListOf("a", "b")
    val anotherList = firstList.plus("c") // creates a new list and returns it. firstList is not changed
    println(firstList) // [a, b]
    println(anotherList) // [a, b, c]

    val isAdded = firstList.add("c") // adds c to the mutable variable firstList
    println(firstList) // [a, b, c]
    println(isAdded) // true

    val unmodifiableList = listOf("a", "b")
    val isAdded2 = unmodifiableList.add("c") // compile error, add is not defined on an UnmodifiableList
}
```

[`plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) creates a new List out of an existing list and a given item or another list and returns the result (the new created List), while the input List is never changed. The item is not added to the existing List.

[`add`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html) is only defined on modifiable Lists (while the default in Kotlin is an ImmutableList) and added the item to the existing List and returns `true` to indicate that the item was added successfully.

Answer (score 7):

Basically:

`plus()` adds element and returns the list containing this new value(s).

> Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection and then the given [element].

So with `plus()`:

```
val list1 = listOf(1,2,3)
val list2 = list1.plus(4) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
val list3 = listOf(0).plus(list2) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`add()` just adds an element and returns bool.

> Adds the specified element to the end of this list. Return `true` because the list is always modified as the result of this operation.

Answer (score 1):

These two are completely different functions.

First of all `add()` can only add one item to mutable collection while `plus()` can add one item of a collection of items.

Second - `add()` function returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the collection was modified or not, while `plus()` returns result immutable `collection`.

The third and most important difference it that - the `plus()` function is a `operator` function overload which means that it is evaluated as static and can be used like this

```
val result = listOf(1,2,3) + 4 // [1,2,3,4]
val result2 = listOf(1,2,3).plus(4) // [1,2,3,4]
val result3 = listOf(1,2,3) + listOf(4,5,6) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
val result4 = listOf(1,2,3).plus(listOf(4,5,6)) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

While `add()` is just a regular instance function of `MutableCollection` interface

Answer (score 0):

If you come from Java world you need to keep in mind that default List in Kotlin is **immutable**. It means that you can't just add elements to this list.

> In Kotlin, plus (+) and minus (-) operators are defined for
>   collections. They take a collection as the first operand; the second
>   operand can be either an element or another collection. The return
>   value is a **new read-only** collection.

But Kotlin also has MutableList(like an usual Java List) where you can add elements to the mutable collection

```
val numbers = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
numbers.add(5)
```